# Corsair Gaming K95 keyboard not working until I switch USB port

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard

I dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
And I have a problem with my [Corsair Gaming K95 keyboard](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Gaming-Keyboards/CORSAIR-Gaming-K95-RGB-Mechanical-Gaming-Keyboard-%E2%80%94-CHERRY%C2%AE-MX-Red/p/CH-9000220-NA) in Ubuntu.

The keyboard works perfectly in *grub* and *Windows*, but after I have selected Ubuntu, my keyboard doesn't work on the login screen, and I have to switch the USB port, sometimes multiple times.

Hope someone can help, ask if you need more information.
I should also add that I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux.